# Exception should not appear in prod

Tags: symfony, nginx

I have this kind of exception, on a production environnement:

> Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Unable to create the cache
> directory
> (/app/ezplatform/var/cache/prod/a6d61d85393d8924b6a2d32272d325510651f125)
> in
> /app/ezplatform/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:765
> Stack trace: #0
> /app/ezplatform/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(642):
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->buildContainer() #1
> /app/ezplatform/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(135):
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer() #2
> /app/ezplatform/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(195):
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot() #3
> /app/ezplatform/web/app.php(64):
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
>
> ## 4 {main} thrown in /app/ezplatform/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php
>
> on line 765

I don't understand why the response http code is 200 instead of 500, is it because a server low level exception ? How to customize the error page for this kind of situation.

This the response header:

```
HTTP/2.0 200 OK
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Wed, 18 Dec 2019 08:32:40 GMT
strict-transport-security: max-age=0
x-debug-info: eyJyZXRyaWVzIjowfQ==
x-request-id: z7m5kvoqa4smukjgb74pxhqd
x-robots-tag: noindex, nofollow
content-length: 982
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by the Symfony cache generator, not by your application.

The application will try to generate it's cache on a folder, from the directory, but it can't access it. The folder `var/cache/` must be allowed to be written by the user that is running the application, maybe your server user.

Changing this with a simple `chmod USER_RUNNING_THE_APP +w var/cache -R` will solve the issue most likely.

As for the issue about the the response header being 200 instead of 500, this is because the server can respond, and responses using the application. The application will return a response as 200 because will this:

- route the response to the application
- application does it's thing to generate an output
- generates that error message
- we have content, so this means it's 200, cause nothing else is specified
- return 200 with the error message

Comment: the real problème beacause I dont have enough disk space Normally Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException return 500 code...SO in production we should return a costumized page...if I'm getting 200 I'cant do nothing ...another day the user will see that exception